# Messages app on my Macbook Pro stopped sending to Android

Tags: iphone, ios, text, sms, android

The Messages app on my Macbook Pro (running High Sierra) suddenly stopped sending text messages to Android devices. I can still send texts to Android users from my iPhone without a problem, but when sending texts from the Messages app on my Macbook Pro it will not send to Android devices. It just started doing this out of the blue yesterday. I have not had an issue until then. And I have not made any updates to the Mac or the iPhone OSs in that time that might cause the problem, but I did install Microsoft Office 2018 on the Mac. Cellular data is turned on on my iPhone as is Send as SMS.

Comment: The operating system of the recipient 's phone doesn't matter when you are sending an SMS.

Answer (score 40):

Text messages from your Mac are actually sent through your iPhone. On your iPhone go to the Settings app → Messages → Text Message Forwarding. You may need to re-do the setup by removing and re-adding your Mac in there.

Comment: That did the trick. I re-imaged my MacBook Pro and had to enable forwarding for the "new" Mac in the message settings on the phone. This had been driving me nuts. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the solution! How in the world that is not turned on by default or at least mentioned in a system notification is beyond me!!

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this by enabling the following setting on my MacBook:

MacBook > Messages > Preferences > iMessage > Settings > You can be reached for messages at: > Check checkbox next to your phone number

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the iMessage icon. I have an Account icon instead. The inability didn't happen until I updated my iPhone 11Pro Max a couple of days ago. I updated my iPad Air 2, can still send; I updated my iMac to Catalina, no problem; my Apple Watch sends them without problems, as well.