# I cant get texts on my Android phone from messages on my Macbook

Tags: macos, messages, apple-id, android

I cant get texts on my Android phone from messages on my Macbook, but only from a few people. Coincidentally its people I've had facetime conversations with. It seems that the Mac has said to itself "these two people communicated in the Apple universe, lets keep it that way".

Are there settings I need to change?

I can send a text from my phone and they receive it, but when they respond it comes to my Messages app on my Macbook and not my phone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely on the sending side, and you certainly can be sure your accounts are set up correctly before you pester them.

See about removing your SMS from your mporarily while you test.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201349
- [Contact switched to Android; how to send texts instead of iMessages?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91287/)

Once you’re sure your account wasn’t told to register messages for you instead of SMS.

Point them to a couple things that can cause their Macs to not send an SMS.

If can send to some SMS but not you, specifically, focus them on your contact card.

- [Messages.app on macOS won't send/receive/display messages to/from one specific contact](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402417/)

If they can’t send to any SMS/Android it’s their SMSs forwarding that needs a look.

- [Messages app on my Macbook Pro stopped sending to Android](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321376/)

Comment: The OP mentions that they facetime with those contacts as well. Not sure one can get Message to force SMS for contacts which e.g. use a Mac for Facetime and an Android phone for text.

Comment: Yes @nohillside there’s a lot here we don’t know yet. Main thing is to be sure they have deregistered their SMS while they test. That complicates things greatly... (And they may have to choose one or the other)